# full read-only mount setting for BTRFS

Tags: btrfs, forensics

I need to mount a BTRFS partition in 100% read-only mode, i.e. no hidden writes onto the disk whatsoever. The "ro" setting is not enough.

I tried some settings. The settings "ro,nologreplay" don't stop the writes.

Answer (score 1):

100% read-only mode can be enforced at the device level with `blockdev`:

```
blockdev --setro /dev/your_btrfs_partition
```

Note that you may still have to use the `norecovery` (`nologreplay`) and other possible `noxyz` mount options if your partition is damaged (I don't know for BTRFS but `norecovery` is needed for e.g. Ext4).

Of course, you can go back to read-write mode with:

```
blockdev --setrw /dev/your_btrfs_partition
```